# Fix protocol for FX trades

Tags: fix-protocol, forex

I'm trying to gather an information about FIX protocol for FX (Foreign Exchange) trades.
Some old sources mention that FIX protocol got extended with FX related message support:
http://www.fixprotocol.org/discuss/read/1a070ffc

But I can't quite find details online.

Basically, I need to understand:

- What message types are to be used. Can I use AI (Allocation Extraction) or should it be FX specific message type?
- Currency/Counter Currency pairs are properly coded.
- Which fields are to be used for quantities and/or for exchange rate.
- What CFI Codes or Security Types should be used.
- What value for Security Exchange (if any) needs to be provided.

Link to a documentation would be sufficient and any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: These will be customised in most places, which should be present in the user level agreement with the counterparty. Not everybody requires the whole gamut of FIX fields in a aFIX message

Answer (score 4):

FIX is a very fudgy protocol, and the reality is such that two different FX brokers could choose to use very different message and field definitions to do the same things.

If you are designing a client to connect to an existing commercial interface, you should really check with your intended counterparty ASAP.  They should have documentation that describes which messages they support, which fields they require, any field customizations, and any "unorthodox" usages of fields.

If you are designing a server system such that multiple parties are connecting *to you*, then you will have some choices to make.  The fudginess of FIX is a double-edge sword for you: you have a lot of freedom to go your own way, but at the same time it's not paint-by-numbers easy to design.  You can just make a best-guess usage of the messages that the default specs provide to you, and make sure to **document it for your clients**.  (In this case, you may want to get some specs from existing counterparties just to get examples.)

Regarding your sources saying that "FIX protocol got extended with FX related message support", most likely that's just new fields and messages.  Looks like those might be in FIX 4.4 and up.

If you want a good source for surfing FIX messages, use [FIXimate](http://fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/).  It's invaluable.

Comment: FIXmate is where I'm trying to get that information. I'm in the position to design one party myself and suggest the solution for the receiving party. But I'd like to do it properly, not just arbitrary message types with arbitrary fields. Since I don't have counterparty's documentation, I have to figure out the proper way myself.

Comment: It makes more sense to think of FIX as a transport layer protocol that comes with a suggested set of messages and fields.  In practice, the messaging is pretty non-standard.  Some counterparties do downright *weird* things, and I haven't found one yet that didn't make customizations to the standard dictionary.  Don't worry too much about doing it "wrong" - any developer with FIX experience has likely seen worse.